# What is an appropriate data object type to save a list of chronological values in

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Overview of my project: I'm logging some live data every 5 seconds and storing as a .json, the name of each file will be the date it was fetched (eg `2016_02_19_07_10_43.json`). I want a separate 'date index file' which contains, in chronological order, the dates (ie the files names) for my fetched data so later i can call each data set via my index (each file also has an associated binary digit)

here is a sample of my data (i'm also saving it as .json)

```
{"2016_02_19_07_10_46": 1, "2016_02_18_10_55_38": 0, "2016_02_19_07_10_44": 1, "2016_02_19_07_10_43": 1, "2016_02_19_07_10_45": 1}
```

As I will be opening the index file and adding a new date/binary pair and then saving back to json, it seems storing as dict is inappropriate. I have run some tests and it seems if you add say 5 values to a dict in one setting and then write to json they stay in the order they were added (ie dicts do have order sometimes), however once the the dict is reopened and more values added the dict then becomes randomly ordered.

So if i was creating the index in one setting, a dictionary would be fine and the json would be ordered, however as i'm reopening the json and turning it into a python dict object the values then scramble. So a list object will be appropriate ?

Just to demonstate what i mean i devised this test:

```
test = {} 

for i in range(5):
    test[i] = i


with open( 'test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(test, f)
```

Produces:

```
{"0": 0, "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4}
```

Then reopening the json and adding more:

```
with open( 'test.json', 'r') as f:
    test=json.load(f)

for i in range(5,10):
    test[i] = i


with open( 'test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(test, f)
```

produces

```
{"5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9, "1": 1, "0": 0, "3": 3, "2": 2, "4": 4}
```

It's interesting as it seems all new added values keep their order however existing values in the dict are jumbled.

Any comments on this and how I should approach saving my index ?

EDIT: @Serbitar
It's interesting though as this preodcues orderd dicts:

```
for i in range(4):
    test = {}

    for i in range(0,5):
        test[i] = i

    print test
```

Output:

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
```

Comment: Make it simple: `json.dump(sorted(test), f)`

Comment: According to what order do you need the keys?

Comment: What is your question?  The title asks "why" order is sometimes maintained, but in the text of your question it's not clear what you really want to know.

Comment: I state in the question i want to sort in chronological order. @ami tavory

Comment: You can use `json.dump(..., sort_keys=True)` if you need to debug the output and a stable key order is important (especially when running automated tests). Otherwise, why do you care? If order is important for the *application*, don't use a mapping, use a list of (key, value) pairs. If you control the whole stack (both the encoding and decoding sides), *perhaps* using an OrderedDict is an option. As for 'why', see the dupe.

Comment: Also see [Items in JSON object are out of order using "json.dumps"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10844064) and [Can I get JSON to load into an OrderedDict in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6921699)

Comment: And please don't confuse *apparent* order with *ordered*. When iterating over a dictionary (to display it, for example) the keys are not randomised. The order this produces is dependent on implementation details. Sequential integers use sequential hashes and are thus often slotted into the dictionary in sequence. That doesn't mean their order is guaranteed.

Comment: So even if I use a list of tuples instead of a dictionairy, json dumps will still scramble the original order ? If i use sort_keys when i dump my json and my keys are dates taking the form `"2016_02_19_07_10_46"` will they be ordered chronologically ?

Comment: I've re-duped the question; to preserve the original link, why you see an *apparent* ordering is an implementation detail, see [Why is the order in Python dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15479928)

Comment: @DavidHancock: no, if you have a list containing key-value pairs, order will be preserved, because lists do maintain order.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries do not guarantee to maintain order. If they do so, it is because you are lucky.

If you want this behaviour you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)
As the name says, it preserves the order of the keys.

Comment: As I said. Normally, dictionaries are orderrd in the way they are initialized. But thats not guaranteed. Python can decide at any operation to change the order it so pleases. If and when this is done depends on python internals. So you can not rely on the dictionary having that order (although it will normally do so).