# Django Rest Framework - How to restructure json response?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework (along with [rest_framework_mongoengine](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine)) and overriding **to_representation()** of my serializer to send back my own custom JSON object. Everything is working fine but the order of JSON fields is messed up. Please tell me how to reorder/restructure the JSON object being sent back. The serializer looks like this:

```
class PharmacySerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    bank_account = serializers.DictField(child=serializers.CharField(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Pharmacy
        fields = (
            'id', 'name', 'email', 'mobile', 'address_line_1', 'address_line_2',
            'city', 'state', 'zip', 'created_by', 'created_on', 'last_updated_by', 'license_number',
            'bank_account', 'last_updated_on', 'is_email_verified', 'is_mobile_verified', 'is_active')
        read_only_fields = ('created_by', 'created_on', 'last_updated_by', 'last_updated_on', 'is_active')

    def to_representation(self, pharmacy):
        return {
            'id': str(pharmacy.id),
            'name': pharmacy.name,
            'email': pharmacy.email,
            'mobile': pharmacy.mobile,
            'address_line_1': pharmacy.address_line_1,
            'address_line_2': pharmacy.address_line_2,
            'city': pharmacy.city,
            'state': pharmacy.state,
            'zip': pharmacy.zip,
            'created_by': pharmacy.created_by,
            'created_on': pharmacy.created_on,
            'last_updated_by': pharmacy.last_updated_by,
            'license_number': pharmacy.license_number,
            'bank_account': {
                'bank_name': pharmacy.bank_account.bank_name,
                'account_number': pharmacy.bank_account.account_number,
                'account_type': pharmacy.bank_account.account_type
            },
            'last_updated_on': pharmacy.last_updated_on,
            'is_email_verified': pharmacy.is_email_verified,
            'is_mobile_verified': pharmacy.is_mobile_verified,
            'is_active': pharmacy.is_active
        }
```

And the response that I am getting is:

```
[
    {
        "city": "City",
        "name": "Some Pharmacy",
        "zip": "778372",
        "mobile": "9880082229",
        "license_number": "SP22",
        "is_mobile_verified": false,
        "is_active": true,
        "created_on": "2016-06-18T19:01:02.901",
        "created_by": null,
        "email": "somepharmacy@gmail.com",
        "state": "State",
        "last_updated_by": null,
        "is_email_verified": false,
        "last_updated_on": "2016-06-18T19:01:02.901",
        "address_line_2": null,
        "id": "57659a6ea3b6561c0f20265e",
        "bank_account": {
            "bank_name": "HSBC",
            "account_type": "Savings",
            "account_number": "663822553"
        },
        "address_line_1": "Address"
    }
]
```

I want it to be in the same order as the return dict of to_representation()

Comment: Have you tried to use a [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: @heaVenShaker Is there any particular reason you are overriding `to_representation()` method? I don't think you need to do that as you are just accessing the attributes on object which DRF will normally return. Without overriding it, you can get the ordered response.

Comment: @RahulGupta I am overriding to_representation() because by default it cannot process "bank_account" as "bank_account" is an EmbeddedDocument (please note that I am using MongoEngine with DRF)

Comment: @heaVenShaker Did you try [`EmbeddedDocumentSerializer`](https://pythonhosted.org/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/serializers/#embeddeddocumentserializer) for `bank_account` field?

Comment: @heaVenShaker Can you post the models also.

Comment: @RahulGupta It worked! thanks for your tip! I used EmbeddedDocumentSerializer and it is working perfectly as I wanted! Somehow I had missed EmbeddedDocumentSerializer and was thinking it did not exist. My bad.

So  the answer for the question asked is still using OrderedList, but for my usage, your suggestion suits better!

Comment: @heaVenShaker Great! Recommended approach would be to use `EmbeddedDocumentSerializer` without the need of overriding `to_representation`. Have updated my ans to include this.

Comment: @RahulGupta I had one more question related to MongoEngine and Django (not DRF): Is settings.py the best place to create connection while using MongoEngine with django? `from mongoengine import connect; connect('DBName', username='DBUser', password='DBPassword')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115021/discussion-between-heavenshaker-and-rahul-gupta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to maintain order of response keys, you can use an [`OrderedDict`.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) But there is one thing you should remember about `OrderedDicts`:

**OrderedDict maintains order only while insertion of keys. The order gets lost while initializing with kwargs.**

From [Python docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

> The `OrderedDict` constructor and `update()` method both accept keyword
>   arguments, but **their order is lost** because Python’s function call
>   semantics **pass-in keyword arguments using a regular unordered
>   dictionary**.

You need to first create an `OrderedDict` instance and then add keys one by one.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def to_representation(self, pharmacy):
    ret = OrderedDict() # initialize on ordereddict

    # insert keys one by one in desired oreder
    ret['id'] = str(pharmacy.id)
    ret['name'] = pharmacy.name
    ret['email'] = pharmacy.email
    ret['mobile'] = pharmacy.mobile
    ret['address_line_1'] = pharmacy.address_line_1
    ret['address_line_2'] = pharmacy.address_line_2
    ret['city'] = pharmacy.city
    ret['state'] = pharmacy.state
    ret['zip'] = pharmacy.zip
    ret['created_by'] = pharmacy.created_by
    ret['created_on'] = pharmacy.created_on
    ret['last_updated_by'] = pharmacy.last_updated_by
    ret['license_number'] = pharmacy.license_number
    ret['bank_account'] = {
        'bank_name' = pharmacy.bank_account.bank_name
        'account_number' = pharmacy.bank_account.account_number
        'account_type' = pharmacy.bank_account.account_type
    }
    ret['last_updated_on'] = pharmacy.last_updated_on
    ret['is_email_verified'] = pharmacy.is_email_verified
    ret['is_mobile_verified'] = pharmacy.is_mobile_verified
    ret['is_active'] = pharmacy.is_active

    return ret
```

**NOTE:** Another option(recommended) is to **use [`EmbeddedDocumentSerializer`](https://pythonhosted.org/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/serializers/#embeddeddocumentserializer) for `bank_account` field.** Then you won't need to override the `to_representation()` method.

Comment: It worked! Thanks Rahul Gupta for your help :) much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Try to return a [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in the `to_representation`:

```
def to_representation(self, pharmacy):
  return OrderedDict([('id', str(pharmacy.id),), ...])
```

The dict object in your code is not ordered in its nature. Assumed the framework use `json.dump` internally, you can keep the order by using a ordered object as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844064/items-in-json-object-are-out-of-order-using-json-dumps).