# Django JSON AJAX data order not right when attached to table

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

What I want is, at the front-end, when the button pressed, retrieve the data from the back-end using Ajax, then attach them to a table. I'm using Django 1.9.

I managed to do so. However, each value does not match each column, just as the picture shows:

[image: data Order is not right]

So that is my problem. CDK should be name, instead of price.

In views.py, I have:

```
def ajax_dict(reuqest):
dicWCWishlist = [{"CDK":"Fallout 4","Price":"￥199", "Addin-Date":"Gifted! Thank you!"}, {"CDK":"Far Cry Primal","Price":"€59.99", "Addin-Date":"2015-12-5"}, {"CDK":"iPhone 6S plus","Price":"$749", "Addin-Date":"2016-1-15"}, {"CDK":"wrong", "Price":"$$999", "Addin-Date":"1980-3-9"}]
return JsonResponse(dicWCWishlist, safe = False)
```

In runAjax.html, I have:

```
        $("#btnJJDBZ").click(function() {
            // alert("Boom!");
            $.get("../ajax_dict/", function(res) {
                for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    var ntr = $("<tr></tr>");                       
                    $.each(res[i], function(key, value) {
                        var ntd = $("<td></td>")                        
                        ntd.html(value);    
                        ntr.append(ntd);            
                    })      
                    $("#tbodyWishlist").append(ntr);
                }
            });
        });
```

Besides, more strangely, whenever I modify the views.py file, the received data order randomly change again. Like when I add a space at any end of the line, or I change price $749 to $750, save and refresh the page, then the price column data moved to Add-in Date, or randomly under some column I don't know.

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

The problem is solved for now, thanks to @luke_aus 's help.

In runAjax.html, change the jquery code with it follows:

```
        $("#btnJJDBZ").click(function(){
            $.get("../ajax_dict", function(res) {
                $.each(res, function(){
                    $.each(this, function(key, value){
                        var ntr = $("<tr></tr>");
                        var ntd1 = $("<td class='CDK'></td>");
                        var ntd2 = $("<td class='Price'></td>");
                        var ntd3 = $("<td class='Addin-date'></td>");
                        $.each(this, function(key, value){
                            switch(key){
                                case "CDK":
                                    ntd1.html(value);
                                    break;
                                case "Price":
                                    ntd2.html(value);
                                    break;
                                case "Addin-Date":
                                    ntd3.html(value);
                                    break;
                            }
                        })
                        ntr.append(ntd1).append(ntd2).append(ntd3);
                        $("#tbodyWishlist").append(ntr);
                    });
                });
            });
```

I changed the data format, too.

```
dicWCWishlist = {"list":[{"CDK":"Fallout 4","Price":"￥199", "Addin-Date":"Gifted! Thank you!"}, {"CDK":"Far Cry Primal","Price":"€59.99", "Addin-Date":"2015-12-5"}, {"CDK":"iPhone 6S plus","Price":"$749", "Addin-Date":"2016-1-15"}, {"CDK":"wrong1", "Price":"$$999", "Addin-Date":"1980-3-9"}]}
```

What I did is basically,

1. Create tr and 3 tds in advance
2. When key comes, manually tell what key it is (using switch)
3. Change the corresponded cell with correct value (using html())

### However, the question is still there!

Why was my data order random?

What did JsonResponse do to my JSON ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it will be to create each row with td's with a class name that corresponds to the JSON object key for each object, then add the data from each object to the corresponding td.

e.g. generate the table per ajax object (rather than per click as per this example)
https://jsbin.com/sihudumere/edit?html,css,output

Then place the data in the correct columns:

`jsonObj[key] = value
newRow.children('.key).text(value)`

Comment: It worked, thanks, but I still wonder why the order was not right.

Comment: this talks about that issue in greater depth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844064/items-in-json-object-are-out-of-order-using-json-dumps

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this

```
ntd.html(value);
```

with this

```
ntd.text(value)
```

Just try it,my brother.