# Write data to .json file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to read all the files in a folder over a certain size and export the data (file path and size) to a .json

What I have so far:

```
import os       
import json
import sys
import io

testPath = str(sys.argv[1])
testSize = int(sys.argv[2])

try:
    to_unicode = unicode
except NameError:
    to_unicode = str

filesList = []
x = 1
j = "1"
data = {}

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(testPath):
    for name in files:
        filesList.append(os.path.join(path, name))

for i in filesList:
    fileSize = os.path.getsize(str(i))
    if int(fileSize) >= int(testSize):
        data['unit'] = 'B'
        data['path' + j] = str(i)
        data['size' + j] = str(fileSize)
        x = x + 1
        j = str(x)


with io.open('Files.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    str_ = json.dumps(data,
                      indent=4, sort_keys=True,
                      separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
    outfile.write(to_unicode(str_))
```

The problem is that the output is:

```
{
    "path1": "C:\\Folder\\diager.xml",
    "path2": "C:\\Folder\\diag.xml",
    "path3": "C:\\Folder\\setup.log",
    "path4": "C:\\Folder\\ESD\\log.txt",
    "size1": "1908",
    "size2": "4071",
    "size3": "5822",
    "size4": "788",
    "unit": "B"
}
```

But it needs to be something like this:

```
{
"unit": "B",
"files": [{"path":"C:\Folder\file1.txt", "size": "10"}, {"path":"C:\Folder\file2.bin", "size": "400"}]
}
```

I added the j variable because it would just replace the first value and I would just end up with something like this:

```
{
    "path": "C:\\Folder\\diager.xml",
    "size": "1908",
    "unit": "B"
}
```

I have no idea how to proceed... Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your data dictionary with:

```
data = {"unit": "B", "files": []}
```

You can then replace your main loop:

```
for i in filesList:
    fileSize = os.path.getsize(str(i))
    if int(fileSize) >= int(testSize):
        data['unit'] = 'B'
        data['path' + j] = str(i)
        data['size' + j] = str(fileSize)
        x = x + 1
        j = str(x)
```

by

```
for i in filesList:
    fileSize = os.path.getsize(str(i))
    if int(fileSize) >= int(testSize):
        data['files'].append({"path": str(i), "size": str(filesize)})
```

Note that you no longer need your x and j variables.

Edit: In order to control the order of the fields, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10844064/4865672). In particular, according to [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23820416/4865672), if you are using python 3.6, you can import OrderedDict (`from collections import OrderedDict`) and replace `data = {"unit": "B", "files": []}` by `data = OrderedDict(unit="B", files=[])`

Comment: In order to control the order of the fields, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10844064/4865672)

Comment: Works like a charm! Also, I just set sort_keys to False instead of True and now it's not printing alphabetically. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
files = []
for i in filesList:
    fileSize = os.path.getsize(str(i))
    if int(fileSize) >= int(testSize):
        files.append({'path': str(i), 'size': fileSize})

data['unit'] = 'B'
data['files'] = files
```

This way, you create a list containing all paths and add it to the `data` dict later.