# Python: Comparing two JSON objects in pytest

Tags: python, json, pytest, object-comparison

I have an API that returns this JSON response

```
{
    "message": "Staff name and password pair not match",
    "errors": {
        "resource": "Login",
        "field": "staff_authentication",
        "code": "invalid",
        "stack_trace": null
    }
}
```

Using pytest, I want to build a copy of the JSON object and make sure it is exactly the same

```
import pytest
import json
from collections import namedtuple
from flask import url_for
from myapp import create_app

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('client_class')
class TestAuth:

    def test_login(self, client):
        assert client.get(url_for('stafflogin')).status_code == 405
        res = self._login(client, 'no_such_user', '123456')
        assert res.status_code == 422
        response_object = self._json2obj(res.data)
        assert response_object.message == 'Staff name and password pair not match'
        invalid_password_json = dict(message="Staff name and password pair not match",
                                    errors=dict(
                                        resource="Login",
                                        code="invalid",
                                        field="staff_authentication",
                                        stack_trace=None,)
                                    )
        assert self._ordered(response_object) == self._ordered(invalid_password_json)

    def _login(self, client, staff_name, staff_password):
        return client.post('/login',
            data=json.dumps(dict(staff_name=staff_name, staff_password=staff_password)),
            content_type='application/json',
            follow_redirects=True)

    def _json_object_hook(self, d): return namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values())
    def _json2obj(self, data): return json.loads(data, object_hook=self._json_object_hook)

    def _ordered(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            return sorted((k, self._ordered(v)) for k, v in obj.items())
        if isinstance(obj, list):
            return sorted(self._ordered(x) for x in obj)
        else:
            return obj
```

`pytest` shows that the 2 objects are unequal.

```
>       assert self._ordered(response_object) == self._ordered(invalid_password_json)
E       AssertionError: assert X(message='St...k_trace=None)) == [('errors', [(...r not match')]
E         At index 0 diff: 'Staff name and password pair not match' != ('errors', [('code', 'invalid'), ('field', 'staff_authentication'), ('resource', 'Login'), ('stack_trace', None)])
E         Full diff:
E         - X(message='Staff name and password pair not match', errors=X(resource='Login', field='staff_authentication', code='invalid', stack_trace=None))
E         + [('errors',
E         +   [('code', 'invalid'),
E         +    ('field', 'staff_authentication'),
E         +    ('resource', 'Login'),
E         +    ('stack_trace', None)]),
E         +  ('message', 'Staff name and password pair not match')]

tests/test_app.py:31: AssertionError
=========================== 1 failed in 0.22 seconds ===========================
```

How do I make the newly created JSON object to the same as the response?

Answer (score 9):

Instead of converting the JSON response into *Object*, I use `json.loads()` to convert it into a **Dictionary**, and compare them.

```py
def test_login(self, client):
        res = return client.post('/login',
            data=json.dumps(dict(staff_name='no_such_user', staff_password='password')),
            content_type='application/json',
            follow_redirects=True)
        assert res.status_code == 422
        invalid_password_json = dict(message="Staff name and password pair not match",
                                    errors=dict(
                                        resource="Login",
                                        code="invalid",
                                        field="staff_authentication",
                                        stack_trace=None,),
                                    )
        assert json.loads(res.data) == invalid_password_json
```

This way, I do not have to worry about whitespace differences in the JSON response, as well as ordering of the JSON structure. Simply let Python's Dictionary comparison function check for equality.

Answer (score 1):

If you do indeed require literal, value-to-value equality between two doctionaries, it would be simpler to compare their json serialization results, otherwise you would need some recursive comparison of dicts and their values

**Note**: since dicts in python are unsorted collections, you would require passing `sort_keys=True` to `json.dumps`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844064/items-in-json-object-are-out-of-order-using-json-dumps) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is `sort_keys=True` necessary? Even when I jumble up the keys, the comparison is still correct.

Comment: If you use python3, it is likely due to the fact that current realization of dict is order-preseving, but as far as I know it is not intended and is not included in the specification, so it can work, but I would not rely on this in the long run.     In python2 I believe this should not be the same _in general_, but for short dicts of fixed key list - it may work without sort_keys

Comment: Python3 has committed that dicts will be ordered going forward, so you can rely on it.

Comment: It's not just that dicts are ordered in modern Python. It's also that dicts *in different order* compare equal.