# How do I make JS fetch function receive json/data from flask API in the same order as sent by flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, bootstrap-vue

How do I make JS fetch receive json/data from flask API in the same order as sent by flask?

**flask API:**

```
@api_bp.route("/users")
def users():
    all_users = User.query.all()
    data = list([u.to_dict() for u in all_users])
    return data
```

print(data):

`[{'id': 1, 'username': 'godo', 'email': 'godo@email.com', 'first_name': 'Godo', 'last_name': 'xxx'}]`

**JS script:**

```
fetch( apiEndpoint + 'users' )
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  this.tableData = data;
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
});
```

data:

`[{'email': 'godo@email.com', 'first_name': 'Godo', 'id': 1, 'last_name': 'xxx', 'username': 'godo'}]`

The order of keys of the JSON when received by JS fetch is altered to a seemingly alphabetical or random order. I have read that there are technical explanations as to why this is the case, but I really need to receive the data in the same order. Reason: I will display this data using Bootstrap-vue in the browser, and the order is important.

Comment: Order of object properties in JavaScript objects is not something you can control and definitely not something you should rely on.

Comment: If the order is important, fetch the keys according to an array that establishes the ordering you need.

Comment: Also you might want to check what the actual JSON payload looks like (the browser Network developer tab will show you that.)

Comment: maybe you should keep in different format - ie. list of lists `[ ['id', 1], ['username', 'godo'], ['email', ...], ...]` but maybe it also may need to change code in  `Bootstrap-vue

Comment: It turns out that BootstrapVue `b-table` has a `fields` attribute that can be used to define the order of columns that will be included in the table. I'll be using it.

Comment: @JeffP the ordering [isn't guaranteed on the Python side either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844064/items-in-json-object-are-out-of-order-using-json-dumps) so you will have to perform some sort of sort into a linear data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the keys in the JSON object is not guaranteed in JavaScript, so the order can be different from the order in which it was sent by Flask. However, you can use an array to specify the order of the keys and then map the data to a new object with the keys in the desired order.

```js
fetch(apiEndpoint + 'users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const orderedData = data.map(obj => {
            return keyOrder.reduce((acc, key) => {
                acc[key] = obj[key];
                return acc;
            }, {});
        });
        this.tableData = orderedData;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    });
```